# AndEngine - SpriteGroup doesn't work for non static sprite

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, game-engine

Recently I had some performance issues with my game
So I decided to use SpriteGroup .

It worked well when I added some static sprite to it
using :

```
levelObject = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.platform1_region, vbom);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, levelObject, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF).setUserData("platform1");

levelObject.setCullingEnabled(true);
spriteGroup_Platform1.draw(levelObject);
```

But when I tried to put dynamic Sprite with some update handlers
Using this code:

```
levelObject = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.coin_region, vbom)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
                    {
                        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                        if (player.collidesWith(this))
                        {
                            addToScore(20);
                            this.setVisible(false);
                            this.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                        }
                    }
                };
                levelObject.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(1, 1, 1.3f)));

                levelObject.setCullingEnabled(true);
                spriteGroup_Coin.draw(levelObject);[/syntax]
```

they didn't response at all.
not to a collide ("onManagedUpdate") , and didn't change their size ("registerEntityModifier")

What am I doing wrong?

Does SpriteGroup support this?

Thanks